# Which ordered objects in .NET are similar to Hashtable?

Tags: .net-4.5

We are in the process of migrating our WCF services from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5. This [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) article states the following:

> Hashtable and similar ordered collection objects that are serialized
>   under the .NET Framework 4.5 cannot be deserialized under the .NET
>   Framework 4.

What other objects are covered under "similar ordered collection objects?"

Comment: This is specific to SoapFormatter, a class that's been obsolete since .NET version 2.0.  Are you sure this matters to you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this class is obsolete. This caused some problems in the company years ago during a .NET upgrade and was brought up as a concern. I've checked with all parties and we are not using this class.